# React JS with laravel, can unauthorize person look at my React JS sourcode at /resources/assets/js/components folder?

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, api, laravel-passport

I'm learning bulding React JS API with laravel (5.6) passport. To acsess API with fetch, my flow more or less is like this;

1. first I declare the API credential
   (`client_id, client_secret, grant_type, username, password, scope`)
   inside my .js file, in /resources/assets/js/components folder
2. requesting a token by fetching to /oauth/token using the credential
   mention above
3. after getting the token, lastly I fetch to my API URL using that
   token

So far so good and everything works, but my concern is since I declare my credential in .js file, I'm afraid that anybody could access the URL and look the source code that contain my credential, because as we all know client can look for the source code of client side code like js, html, or css.

So my question is;

1. is there a way to prevent that?

Or

2. is my method fundamentally wrong to declare a credential in
   /resources/assets/js/components/.js file? if so can anybody
   enlighten me to the best practice and safe method to do so.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be fundamentally wrong, you should probably use a database of some sort and password protect it

Comment: Can you elaborate the step to do so (or at least guide me to some thread or URL), because as far as my limited brain could think of, to first get the credential from the database, require to first fetch it from the.js file, but then it means that the destination API URL to fetch it, is unprotected, because its the first thing to do/call before even we have the credential. and second is it usafe to safe a password in plain string in database, because,  to declare the credential, it needs the password in plain string.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing any sensetive data in your javascript, these values can be retrieved easily.

Comment: ok then can you give an idea to supply that credential to fetch to my API ? without declaring it infile.